# Campo <input> sobrepondo campo calendário

Tags: php

Bom dia!!
Estou com o seguinte problema, tenho um campo de texto com ícone, porém, quando seleciono o campo do calendário logo abaixo, o campo input está sobrepondo o campo calendário. Alguma ideia do que possa ser?? Segue abaixo o código e a imagem auto-explicativa.

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label>Nome</label>
    <div id="listas">
    <div class="input-group">
        <input class="form-control" name="colaborador" id="colaborador" value="" required>
        <span class="input-group-btn">
           <button class="btn btn-primary" type="button" id="add_field"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i></button>
        </span>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>                              
<div class="form-group">
    <label>Data Inicial</label>
    <input class="form-control" name="dataInicial" value="" id="datepicker" data-mask="00/00/0000" style="width:100px" required>
</div>
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Tem algum código css ?

Comment: Ele usa o CSS do bootstrap.

Comment: Possivelmente é o z-index definido. Use o inspecionar elemento para verificar os valores;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Na classe `.ui-datapicker` coloque:

```
.ui-datapicker {
  z-index 9999 !important;
}
```

Que irá resolver seu problema.

Comment: Deu certo, obrigado!